# How to insert a row of df1 one time in two rows of df2 in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to insert rows of a specific dataframe one time in two rows in another specific dataframe. At the end, I'd like to do this for several columns of df1 and df2 (not only D and E).

I've got two different dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'], 
                    'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
                    'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
                    'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3']},
                  index=[0, 1, 2, 3])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'], 
                    'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
                    'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
                    'E': ['E0', 'E1', 'E2', 'E3']},
                   index=[0, 1, 2, 3])
```

And I'd like to merge them like

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A0', 'A1', 'A1', 'A2', 'A2', 'A3', 'A3'],
                    'B': ['B0', 'B0', 'B1', 'B1', 'B2', 'B2', 'B3', 'B3'],
                    'C': ['C0', 'C0', 'C1', 'C1', 'C2', 'C2', 'C3', 'C3'],
                    'D': ['D0', 'E0', 'D1', 'E1', 'D2', 'E2', 'D3', 'E3']},
                   index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** Using `pd.concat` and `sort_index`

```
In [1006]: (pd.concat([df1, df2.rename(columns={'E': 'D'})])
              .sort_index().reset_index(drop=True))
Out[1006]:
    A   B   C   D
0  A0  B0  C0  D0
1  A0  B0  C0  E0
2  A1  B1  C1  D1
3  A1  B1  C1  E1
4  A2  B2  C2  D2
5  A2  B2  C2  E2
6  A3  B3  C3  D3
7  A3  B3  C3  E3
```

**2)** Or, Using `append` and `sort_index`

```
In [1007]: df1.append(df2.rename(columns={'E': 'D'})).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
Out[1007]:
    A   B   C   D
0  A0  B0  C0  D0
1  A0  B0  C0  E0
2  A1  B1  C1  D1
3  A1  B1  C1  E1
4  A2  B2  C2  D2
5  A2  B2  C2  E2
6  A3  B3  C3  D3
7  A3  B3  C3  E3
```

---

Test

```
In [1009]: (pd.concat([df1, df2.rename(columns={'E': 'D'})])
              .sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
              .equals(df3))
Out[1009]: True

In [1010]: pd.concat([df1, df2.rename(columns={'E': 'D'})]).equals(df3)
Out[1010]: False
```

Answer (score 0):

The concat function lets you combine multiple DataFrames:

```
frames = [df1, df2.rename(columns={'E': 'D'})]
pd.concat(frames)
```

You can additional DataFrames to the list, but you will have to rename columns to have have merge correctly.